# How to make a file version number in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, image

I am saving PNG images and would like each individual image to have its own version number.

I was originally doing this in C# and saving every PNG file and adding on `?v=54165` which gives the file its own unique number while keeping it as a png, so for example the whole file would look like this:

```
imagename.png?v=67485
```

The problem is that in Windows you cannot save an image with a question mark in the filename as it is a reserved character. I would be grateful if someone could provide an alternative?

**EDIT: I need the number to be after the file extension.**

Comment: imageName2433.png... sorted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It needs to be after the file extension though.

Comment: _"It needs to be after the file extension though"_  - there is no such thing as _"after the file extension"_

Comment: You don't really want to change the extension by adding a version number behind it since it wouldn't be recognized as a png anymore. Is it an option to store it in a database (at least the url) so you can add an extra field with a version number?

Comment: Put the version in the file as _metadata_

Comment: Thanks for the reply MickyD and  Mark Baijens. So its not feasible to have a file imagename.png54465 while still keeping the file as a png?

Comment: renaming the file to `imagename.png54465` makes it **no longer a PNG**

Comment: @MickyD Technically it is still a PNG regardless of name/extension. Your best option is `<name>.<version>.png` though.

Comment: @Lloyd Windows isn't OSX.  Whether the file claims internally to be a PNG or not matters not to Windows or file associations

Comment: @MickyD Right. But in that same breath of _Windows isn't OSX_ you can't make Windows into OSX either, you get what you're given and have to work with that.

Comment: "I need the number to be after the file extension."   Nope. Put the version at the start of the filename, build and ship it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not possible in Windows to add any information after extension in filename. It is better to save image as
 'imagename__v67485.png' to avoid complexity in filename